# validate sharedelement transition after canvas.scale android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-transitions

I did a couple of google searches and couldnt figure this one out.
I am trying to duplicate the google photo behaviour that when one pinches a image the image transitions back to the place.

everything is working. 
the only problem is when the back transition is happening the transition happends from the old full size image.

to be more clear i scale the canvas of the rootview of my activity so that everything inside the activity is scaled down.
in this case the content inside the rootview is just a image.
in the end of the pinch the scalefactor will be 0.5f. (50% of the normal size)
then the return transition takes place and the problem happends. the transition scales up to the original(100%) size before animating, this makes it look like the scaling of the canvas never happend.

i hope this is clear english is not my native language.

code:

```
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,mScreenX,mScreenY);

    canvas.rotate(mRotationDegree,mScreenX,mScreenY);

    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that canvas does not update all the way, i converted to setScaleY and setScaleX on the viewgroup